# How Facetime app launches automatically even if the app is killed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facetime

I want to know how iOS Facetime app launches automatically on call from other device even if the app is killed?I want to achieve the same for my app.

Thanks!

Comment: You do realize that Facetime is an app made by Apple? Different rules apply to their apps. You cannot reproduce many of their functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

You should never assume that a feature of an Apple app is available to 3rd-party apps.  In this case, there is no way to launch your app into the foreground on demand.  The best you can do is use Push Kit and send a notification which launches your app into the background to generate a local notification.

Comment: I am already aware of Pushkit but I want to launch the app completely.You are right I should not assume thats why i posted it on SO.

Comment: Well, you have your answer.